# regex for number followed by letters

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing

I am trying get the Regex right for the following scenario but have some trouble. Below is the scenario.

My string looks like this: `141st ST or 141ST ST`

I want to get only the `141st` part

Comment: Where's the trouble?

Comment: in both case you could explode on space

Comment: I dont know how to write the regex expression to catch the "141st"

Comment: something like that: /[0-9]+st/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

`[0-9]{3}[A-Za-z]{2}`

3 numbers with

> `[0-9]{3}`

1 to 3 digits with

> `[0-9]{1,3}`

and 2 letters with

> `[A-Za-z]{2}`

Comment: If you only want the part where the letters are lowercase, you can change `[A-Za-z]` to `[a-z]`

Comment: How about when the number could be from 1 to 3 characters?

Comment: You can use {1,3} . Also added to answer

Comment: I tried it and it didnt work. The number is at the beginning of the line, I dont know if that makes a difference

Comment: At this point I'd recommend going to [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/) and testing the expressions out for yourself until you have exactly what you need.

Comment: Being at beginning of line does not make difference [0-9]{1,3}[A-Za-z]{2} would give result you want. 1 to 3 digits followed by 2 letters.

Comment: And probably you forgot to remove ^ character from start of regex. This means only looks starting of the string.

Comment: This did the job ^[0-9]{1,3}[A-Za-z]{2}. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be cool you could do it this way to validate the street number too:

```
\d{0,2}(?:1st|2nd|3rd|[04-9]th)(?= st)
```

and just use the case insensitive flag

Comment: You beat me to it.  :)